# Find position of distinct words in string without overlapping

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I am trying to search for certain words/strings in a text string and get their positions into a dictionary.

An example will explain better what I am trying to accomplish and what are my issues.

```
content = """Learning python is something I always wanted to do. The fact that python is a simple and intuitive language made me feel bad for learning other programming languages in the first place. I think the main reason why I didn't choose the python language was the fact that I didn't do a proper research about the pros and cons of the available programming options. I gues that writing this paragraph about learning the python language it's harder than the python script I'm trying to accomplish. No, I'm just kidding, if this was the case then I would have completed writing the python languaguage and didn't bother you guys anymore."""

mylist = ['python', 'dummy keyword', 'python language', 'learning the python language', 'another keyword']

dictKw = {}
for x in mylist:
    x = x.lower()
    listKw = []
    for m in re.finditer(x, contentLower):
        #print (x  , " found " , m.start(), m.end())
        listKwPos = []
        listKwPos = [m.start(), m.end()]
        listKw.append(listKwPos)
        dictKw [x] = listKw

print dictKw
```

So here I am searching the **content** string for every keyword found in **mylist** and I'm storing the start and end position of every occurrence into a dictionary having the keyword as key and a list of lists for the keyword positions.

Printing the **dictKw** I get:

```
{'python': [[9, 15], [66, 72], [234, 240], [414, 420], [451, 457], [574, 580]], 'learning the python language': [[401, 429]], 'python language': [[234, 249], [414, 429]]}
```

First of all, I think the keys order in the dictionary is wrong - **python, learning the python language, python language** instead of **python, python language, learning the python language**. I see that when appending the **listKw** list it places the **learning the python language** key between **python** and **python language** instead of placing it in the end.

I think the correct result should be:

```
{'python': [[9, 15], [66, 72], [234, 240], [414, 420], [451, 457], [574, 580]], 'python language': [[234, 249], [414, 429]], 'learning the python language': [[401, 429]]}
```

Now I'd like to delete the list elements of the keywords overlapping each other maintaining an initial priority of the first keywords in **mylist**

In our example **python** is overlapping **python language** so the first time this happens, the **python language** should lose the first list of position so the result would be:

```
{'python': [[9, 15], [66, 72], [234, 240], [414, 420], [451, 457], [574, 580]], 'python language': [[414, 429]],'learning the python language': [[401, 429]]}
```

When checking for the remaining overlap the priority should change so python would lose the overlapping list elements so the result would be:

```
{'python': [[9, 15], [66, 72], [234, 240], [451, 457], [574, 580]], 'python language': [[414, 429]],'learning the python language': [[401, 429]]}
```

and so on. So if we would encounter a 3rd overlap the priority should switch to **python** again so **python language** would lose the start/end element list.

After this check is complete the **python language** and **learning the python language** overlap check should follow resulting in removal of the list values of the **learning the python language** dictionary key.

The final result should be:

```
{'python': [[9, 15], [66, 72], [234, 240], [451, 457], [574, 580]], 'python language': [[414, 429]],'learning the python language': [[]]}
```

Now for this overlapping problem part, I have no idea where to begin so I ask for your help to point me into the right direction or maybe provide another approach for what I am trying to accomplish.

Please keep in mind that the **mylist** elements could have any other order and the order of the elements dictates the keyword priority - top ones have the highest priority.

Comment: The keys in a dictionary have no order by definition! So, you cannot say, the have the wrong order. When printing a dict-Object, the key-Values are printed in a random order.

Comment: Additionally, it seems, that your example is not sound. When you try to avoid overlaps in general, you should also consider the overlaps of `python`and `python language` and remove the `[414,420]`-match of the `python` keyword!

Answer (score 0):

Note that in python, the dictionaries `{"a": 1; "b": 2; "c": 3}` and `{"b":2 ; "a" : 1; "c": 3}` are equivalent - by default the keys are completely unordered.  To fix this, you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html), which will order the elements of the dictionaries by the order key/value pairs are added to them.